# Ajax request issue in sencha touch 2

Tags: authentication, oauth, sencha-touch-2

I have a problem with sending  an ajax request for the authentification..
i dont get errors but Network in chrome says : method : get , status : canceled , type : pending 
and no response from this request ..
when i click on the file connection.js it point in this line :

```
             // start the request!
              xhr.send(requestOptions.data);
```

& my path name and the method get have the color RED

here is my code :

```
   Ext.onReady(function() {
          Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'https://api.mysite.com/api/oauth/',
        method: 'GET',
        useDefaultXhrHeader:false,
        disableCaching: false,
        timeout:120000,

        params: {
            client_id: 'xxxxxx',
            client_secret: 'xxx',
            format: 'json'
        },
        success: function(response) {

            var resultat = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
     //the response is :           {"status":"ok","auth_token":"xxxxxxxxxxx"}
            if (resultat.status === "ok") {
                if (!resultat.access_token === "") {

                    access_token = resultat.access_token;
                    me.sessionToken = resultat.sessionToken;
                }
                else
                {
                    new Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: 'https://api.mysite.com/api/oauth/signin',
                        method: 'post',
                        params: {
                            username: username,
                            password: password,
                            authtoken: resultat.access_token,
                            format: 'json'
                        },
                        success: function(response) {

                            var loginResponse = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);

                            if (loginResponse.success === "true") {
                                // The server will send a token that can be used throughout the app to confirm that the user is authenticated.
                                me.sessionToken = loginResponse.sessionToken;
                                me.signInSuccess();     //Just simulating success.
                            } else {
                                me.signInFailure(loginResponse.message);
                            }
                        },
                        failure: function(response) {
                            me.sessionToken = null;
                            me.signInFailure('Login failed. Please try again later.');
                        }

                    });

                }
                // The server will send a token that can be used throughout the app to confirm that the user is authenticated.


            } else {
                //exception
            }
        }
           ,
           failure: function(response) {
                 me.sessionToken = null;
                  Ext.Msg.alert('failed !!');    // its what it shows me 
                }
         });
```

Comment: What you want to do is clear but what's not is what's blocking you.

Comment: i'm new in sencha touch , i dont know how to proceed ,i need some help :) an example , i edited my post i put the algorithm , plz corect my errors .

Comment: algorithm wise it seems fine all you have to put it in syntactically correct code by making few changes like `Ext.Ajax.request` instead of `Ext.Ajax` and `success` instead of `getaccesstoken`. Also you might want to put POST function outside the success handler of GET method and call it only when condition is met. Still not sure what is stopping you from trying out code and see if its working or not.

Comment: i made the modifications but not the last one , i dont know how to do it , but i think thats optionnel , i tried the code , no errors in the console , & nothing is happening , its loading with no effect ...